# Combine two query sets based on shared field

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have two query sets that look like this:

```
product_first = Reports.objects.filter(product='product1', type='week', profile__team=team).select_related('profile')

product_second = Reports.objects.filter(product='product2', type='week', profile__team=team).select_related('profile')
```

Each of those share `obj.profile.user.username`, and have other similiar attributes (`obj.total`, for instance) - I am trying to end up with a query set based on `obj.profile.user.username`, but with the `obj.total` being `product_first.total + product_second.total`.

Example of that table I'm querying:

```
user_id  total  total_items  product    type
1        150    15           product1   week
1        180    19           product2   week
```

Comment: So for every `user_id`, you want toe sum of the totals? What if there are multiple `product1`s and/or `product2`s for that user?

Comment: Right. Fortunately, that table will only have have one entry for each type of product. The data there comes from a CSV that's imported that already totals each product. I could iterate through the CSV and combine totals with and set a product type of "all" or something, I suppose, but I wanted to avoid that route for a few reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this by annotating, and grouping on the `username`:

```
from django.db.models import F, Sum

qs = Reports.object.filter(
    product__in=['product1', 'product2'],
    type='week',
    profile__team=team
).values('profile_id').annotate(
    username=F('profile__user__username')
    the_total=Sum('total')
).order_by('profile_id', 'username')
```

This will result in a `QuerySet` of dictionaries, each dictionary containing three keys: `'profile_id'`, `'username'`, and `'the_total'`. So for the given sample data, it will look like:

```
<QuerySet [{'profile_id': 1, 'username': 'foo', 'the_total': 330}]>
```

(given `'foo'` is the `username` of the user with `id=1`).

Note that the `the_total` will contain the *sum* of the `total`s of all the `product1`s and `product2`s. If the there is no `product2` then it will still show the sum of the `product1`s. If there are *multiple* `product1`s, it will sum up these.

Comment: That's exactly what I was going for. Now to dig into the documentation because that seems like magic. Thank you!

Comment: Is there a way to get an average using the aggregated values of `total` and `total_items`? Effectively, in `annotate()` I have `total_items=Sum('total_items')`, `total=Sum('total')` which returns the expected values, and I want to do `average=total/total_items`. I attempted `average=total/total_items` and got an error that neither `total` or `total_items` were defined, even though I was getting the correct values in the `QuerySet` for both.

Comment: Yes, `average=Avg('total')` (with `from django.db.models import Avg). Note that you better *not* use the same name as one of the fields, since that can result in incorrect queries.

Comment: That gives me the average of `product_1` and `product_2` `total`s (`product_1_total + product_2_total / 2`, where I'm attempting `product_1_total + product_2_total / product_1_total_items + product_2_total_items`. Would I need to iterate through the QuerySet of dictionaries and create a new key for the total average?

Comment: Ah, you want the *average* of (all these products)?

Comment: Right. I think I'm on the right track with `average=Sum(F('total')/F('total_items'), output_field=IntegerField())`, but not sure how to handle `division by zero`

Comment: Also still got a division by zero error when trying `average=Case(When(total=0, then=None), default=F('total')/F('total_items'), output_field=IntegerField())`

Comment: Can you perhaps first explain what exactly you want to calculate (perhaps it is better to ask a separate question, such that other users can see this as well).

Comment: I'm displaying the total price (of all items sold), the total number of items sold, and want to show the average of total items sold. I'm able to do it with a `for` loop (`for each in q: q['average'] = q['total'] / q['total_items`), but didn't know if that was the best way to do it, instead of inside `q.(...).annotate()`